# R: is there something like iPython notebook (jupyter) for R?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

As mentioned in question is there something like iPython's notebook (jupyter) for R-CRAN?

Comment: What about Knitr and Rstudio??

Comment: The rmagic
package allows you to use R code in the iPython notebook;
examples 
[here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/ipython/ipython/3607712653c66d63e0d7f13f073bde8c0f209ba8/docs/examples/notebooks/rmagic_extension.ipynb)
and 
[here](http://www.randalolson.com/2013/01/14/filling-in-pythons-gaps-in-statistics-packages-with-rmagic/).

Comment: Yes, there is a [quick and dirty R kernel for IPython by the IPython author](https://github.com/fperez/ipython-rkernel) and [a more substantial R kernal for IPython here](https://github.com/takluyver/IRkernel), as well as [RCloud](https://github.com/att/rcloud) which aims to be very similar to IPython, providing a notebook interface to R

Comment: Yes, iPython has evolved into the [Jupyter Project](http://jupyter.org/), which fully supports interactive iPython-style notebooks for Python, R and Julia. There is a test-drive server here: https://tmpnb.org

Comment: There is also the beaker notebook http://sharing.beakernotebook.com/gist/anonymous/a119ba0126f280b2d041

Comment: In 2016, RStudio developers developed R Notebook format. See http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html

Comment: Current solution: https://irkernel.github.io

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have a look at Ramnath's R notebook:

http://www.youtube.com/embed/3niqZhc_Nbo

And here's the GitHub: https://github.com/ramnathv/rNotebook

**EDIT** (1/6/15)

I think the new **editR** package is what you're after

https://github.com/swarm-lab/editR

Comment: This totally misses the mark on what a notebook is.  It is just for producing pretty looking documents, but it doesn't provide a way to work interactively (as an alternative to the command line)

Comment: @TylerRinker I did arrive here by searching for IPython for R.  The project you link to is not an alternative to IPython, despite the claims of its author (who seems to be confused about what a notebook interface is).  "rNotebook" appears to be focused on embedding R code (and its result) in a document, i.e. creating a report/presentation.  It is not about working interactively, which is the main purpose of notebook interfaces, including both Mathematica (the system pioneering the notebook interface), and IPython (whose notebook is inspired by Mathematica).

Comment: @Szabolcs Does **editR** suit you moreso?

Comment: It also looks like a report generation tool, focused on creating pretty documents.  It's not a notebook in the sense how Mathematica, IPython, or even MATLAB's Cell mode works.  IPython now has some support for R, which is the only proper R notebook that I have seen.

Comment: Can you give a link for a demo/video of what you're defining as a notebook?  I ask because it seems **editR** does this: http://ipython.org/notebook.html  Though the output is side by side rather than under, though instant.

Answer (score 20):

Not sure it would be an exact equivalent of iPython's notebooks, but you can use `knitr` to make literacy programming in R, by inserting code chunks inside a document. If you use a format like *RMarkdown*, you can export the document and the result of the code chunks to HTML. You can then publish the HTML file somewhere, or use sites like [Rpubs](http://www.rpubs.com). This process is quite straightforward if you use the RStudio IDE.

Another way, if you are an Emacs user, is to use `org-mode` and its extension `org-babel`.

Finally, you should be able to create more dynamic things with a framework like shiny. See for example the following knitr demo from the `shiny` library :

```
R> library(shiny)
R> demo("notebook", package = "knitr")
```

Answer (score -1):

Would this be what you are looking for? http://www.rstudio.com/ide/

Comment: He is looking for a Markdown type solution where he can punblish the work too, not an environment like eclipse.